# how to show latitude and longitude position in google map after sax xml parsing

Tags: android

I have parsed this [XML](http://site4demo.com/artealdiaonline/output.php?lat=-34.6394879&lng=-58.3617837kkj) with a custom SAX parser. I have also prepared a Google map in my MapActivity subclass. How do I pass the longitude and latitude coordinates to the MapActivity?

Comment: hii..pls i am looking for ans.....

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) to pass the lat/long to a MapActivity subclass after you parse that data.